# azure SSH task to unzip the file in remote server linux

Tags: ssh, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

i am using Azure CI/CD pipeline to deploy code to remote server on centOS. i have a zip file residing in the remote server. and i am using this piece of task to unzip the file. but pipeline fails saying host key verification failed.(pipeline is successfully connected to the remoteserver)

```
- task: SSH@0
              inputs:
                sshEndpoint: 'CentOS FTA VM APP1 CBVR'
                runOptions: 'inline'
                inline: |
                  ssh cbvr@172.22.159.132 'cd opt/cbvr/;unzip -o EQ.MaxitCostBasis.Web.zip -d'
                readyTimeout: '20000'
```

Answer (score 0):

> host key verification failed

Based on the error message, you could run the following command to  put the rsa key of the target host into the source host.

```
ssh-keyscan -t rsa targethost(e.g. IP Address) >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
```

For more info, you could refer to this doc: [Auth with SSH](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/use-ssh-keys-to-authenticate?view=azure-devops#q-after-running-git-clone-i-get-the-following-error-what-should-i-do)

Comment: key is already installed,  my question is the inline script what i have in ssh task is it the right command to unzip the file